# Timeout waiting for task Error while getting Large sized fulltext-indexed data from Elastic Search on my Java Project

Tags: java, elasticsearch, resttemplate

I am trying to fetch Indexed data from Elastic search through my java project. The data is **full-text indexed** and the size is about **4gb** and the **index count = 15500 indexes.**
 Also I have increased the Elastic Search Heap Memory size to **ES_HEAP_SIZE=10gb** to avoid the Elastic Search Out Of Memory Heap space Exception when  Indexing and again during fetching the GET request for data.

Now the problem is every time I do the Elastic search GET request for this data I Get  **Timeout waiting for task  Error [org.elasticsearch.transport] [Todd Arliss] Received response for a request that has timed out** in my console but Elastic Search does not show any error or exception and is working fine.

As I am using RestTemplate in my request therefore I thought may the time-out was because of this and so I set the Rest Template time-out to 0. But it did not solve my problem.

Also previously I have fetched data of **size 1.23Gb** with **index count = 25000 files**, but I did not get any such error at that time.
Another Thing is that when I don't do Full text Indexing of this Data then the GET request for the above 4GB data is successful and I can see my indexes successfully on my project UI, while the full-Text indexed GET request fails.

Can anybody please explain why this is happening and how can I resolve this??
 Early answers will be too helpful.